# AlarmManager Android set doesn't work second time

Tags: android, alarmmanager

First sorry for my english.
I have a list of alarms and I need to wake up the application with a notification in a specific time. I only put one alarm at a time.
I put an alarm with the set function, it works, then I put the next alarm in the broadcast but it doesn't wake up at time. Why?
The milliseconds are diferent and correct but the alarm doesn't work.

```
public static void setNextAlarma(long milisegundos){
    Bundle extras = new Bundle();
    extras.putString("mensaje", "message");
    Intent i = new Intent(InfoApp.ALERT_MANAGER);
    i.putExtras(extras);

    PendingIntent pintent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(InfoApp.miContexto, (int) milisegundos, i, 0);

    if (milisegundos != 0){
        InfoApp.miContexto.registerReceiver(AlertasBrCast, new IntentFilter(InfoApp.ALERT_MANAGER));

        AlarmManager alarm = (AlarmManager)InfoApp.miContexto.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);

        alarm.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, milisegundos, pintent);

    }
    else{
        AlarmManager alarm = (AlarmManager)InfoApp.miContexto.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        alarm.cancel(pintent);
    }
}

public final static BroadcastReceiver AlertasBrCast = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();

            String mensaje = "";
            if (extras != null)
                mensaje = extras.getString("mensaje");

            generateNotification(context, mensaje, Calendario.class, null);

            updateAlarm();
        }
    };

    public void updateAlarm(){
// Consult the next alarm in the database 
long fechaNuevaMilli = (Utilidades.strToDate(nuevaFecha,
                    InfoApp.formatoSQL)).getTime();


            Utilidades.setNextAlarma(fechaNuevaMilli);
}
```

Thank you

Comment: Where is the code of `updateAlarm(true)`?

Comment: i consult the next alarm in the database and then call setNextAlarm to put the new one

Answer (score 0, accepted):

alarm.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, milisegundos, pintent); will set the alarm once only user setRepeating function specify the delay interval

here is perfect solution

[Alarm Manager Example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4459058/alarm-manager-example)

Comment: I have a problem with this. It works but if the application is in background the alarm don't work. Where is the problem? Thank you!